# Unable to remove last comma from string

Tags: apex-code

I am trying to remove the last comma in a string using the substring method:

```
system.debug('******************* quoteQuery ' + quoteQuery);
quoteQuery = quoteQuery.subString(0,quoteQuery.Length()-1);
system.debug('******************* quoteQuery ' + quoteQuery);
```

This is the string debug output:

```
DEBUG|******************* quoteQuery SELECT phone,  lineitemcount,  additionalstreet,  expirationdate,  shippingname,  contactid,  createdbyid,  shippinghandling,  additionalstate,  billingcity,  description,  isdeleted,  quotetostate,  quotenumber,  systemmodstamp,  fax,  totalprice,  status,  quotetocountry,  shippingcity,  quotetopostalcode,  billingpostalcode,  shippingstate,  createddate,  subtotal,  discount,  tax,  email,  shippingpostalcode,  lastmodifiedbyid,  additionalcountry,  billingstate,  billingcountry,  lastmodifieddate,  id,  name,  pricebook2id,  shippingstreet,  opportunityid,  quotetocity,  additionalpostalcode,  billingname,  additionalcity,  shippingcountry,  additionalname,  grandtotal,  billingstreet,  issyncing,  quotetoname,  quotetostreet,
```

The last comma is not getting removed?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the complete string

```
quoteQuery.subString(0,quoteQuery.Length()-1);
```

So instead of `Lenght()-1` try `Length()-2`

```
quoteQuery = quoteQuery.subString(0,quoteQuery.Length()-2);
```

Comment: If there is no comma on the end you will end up removing last character.